# Changed dynamically added input value not showing up in jQuery html()?

Tags: jquery, input

I'm working on a To Do list application that dynamically adds list items containing input fields. When I change the value of an input, I can see that it has changed (obviously) and it also has changed according to get the val() via jQuery.

```
    $('#theList').on('change', '.listItem', function(e){
    currentList = $(this).val();
    alert(currentList); /* Changed value appears */
});
```

However, my ultimate goal is to get the innerHTML of the entire  tag and save that via local storage. So, if I do this:

```
    $('#theList').on('change', '.listItem', function(e){
    currentList = $('#theList').html();
    alert(currentList); /* List with unchanged value appears */
});
```

I get all the list items in their original state - and the changed value is discarded.

I'm using the .on() method rather than the deprecated/removed .live() one. My entire routine is wrapped in document.ready().

What am I missing?

Head banging wall Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the value with `val()` or manually with user input doesn't change the HTML attribute, it changes the elements value property and you can't get that with `html()`.

You can change the value with `attr('value', 'something')` and it will change the attribute, and also the markup you get whith `html()`, but you should really rethink the whole concept of storing the markup in localStorage and instead store just the key/values.

Answer (score 0):

How about [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)ing the new content to your #theList div before showing it's content?

Another approach would be to replace the whole content via [jQuery's .html() method](http://api.jquery.com/html/), see the following example.

Code example:

```
$('#theList').on('change', '.listItem', function(e){
    currentList = $(this).val();
    alert(currentList); /* Changed value appears */
    $('#theList').html(currentList);
});
```

PS: I didn't test it... but if you offer a jsFiddle I'm willing to do so ;)